# How do I localize the Grid from the Telerik MVC Extensions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik

I've been using the Grid of the Telerik MVC Extensions with great success, it's a great component. But now I need it's text to be in spanish.

Looking for in the source code, I've only found that I can enable Globalization like this

```
Html.ScriptRegistrar().Globalization(true);
```

But all this line does is inserting some jQuery that tells the grid how to display the numbers and dates (dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy for example).
I'm thinking to make my own version of the Filtering script to insert spanish strings, and then, I'll exchange the english version for the spanish version dynamically.

Have you found another solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating your own version of the filtering script is the only solution for now.

Update:
We have implemented localization support since the Q1 2009 release (assembly version 2009.1.309).

Comment: Is there a plan to support this in the future? Thx!

Comment: @AtanasKorchev We are having s separate resource database for handling localized string.So is there any way to use that values in telerik. I need the values in footer like "Displaying 1 of 1000" to another language ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Q3 2011, and I setup the globalization in the web.config file with the uiCulture value equal to **es-ES**.

Here is the code fragment of the config file:

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>

    <globalization
        enableClientBasedCulture="false"
        culture="es-CO"
        uiCulture="es-ES"/>
</system.web>
```